# Unable to Subscribe topic Published on Google Cloud Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a application for publish particular data on a topic in GOOGLE
CLOUD
The code available on the google documentation which i used to publish data
(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage).

It works fine.Now i want to subscribe this TOPIC.What i do is

Open a new Terminal(Linux mint)

Then I follow the following steps

1. $ virtualenv env
2. $ source env/bin/activate
3. $ pip install -r requirements.txt(Installing Appopriate Libraries)

4.Then I run my Subscriber.py File

```
        def create_subscription(project,topic_name,subscription_name): 
           subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
           topic_path = subscriber.topic_path(project, topic_name)
           subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, 
           subscription_name)
           subscription = subscriber.create_subscription(
           subscription_path, topic_path)
           print('Subscription created: {}'.format(subscription))

     def receive_messages(project, subscription_name):

        subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
        subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project, subscription_name)

        def callback(message):
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
        message.ack()

        subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
        print('Listening for messages on 
        {}'.format(subscription_path))
        while True:
        time.sleep(60)
  //calling above methods using appropriate parameters
    create_subscription("test-1-180006","TOPIC","SUB1")
    receive_messages("test-1-180006","SUB1")
```

But When i run the above code it works fine but nothing is shown.Only shows the below message

```
   Listening for messages on projects/test-1-180006/subscriptions/SUB1
```

Comment: What is in `requirements.txt`? It is hard to understand, without knowing. Also, provide a complete, minimal, verifiable example. The code you have provided cannot be executed as it stands.

Comment: it includes   google-cloud-pubsub==0.28.3 only
i made some changes on the code.

Comment: And are any messages actually being published such that your subscriber would see them?

Comment: http POST ":8080/pubsub/push?token=123" < sample_message.json  i run this code on TERMINAL. It works as i said on  the beginning of the question

Comment: Are you publishing to the right topic?

Comment: Are you publishing messages _after_ you create your subscription?